# Custom rule set for cloudflare to block attacking IPs for specific rules

Tags: reverse-proxy, firewall, cloudflare, cloudflare-apps

Its been more then a month that my websites are under L7 attack. with help of custom rule sets in cloudflare i'm succeeded to mitigate 55% attack. I want to setup a rule to block IP (instead of action). is that possible?

[image: this is my custom rule set. How can i configure it to block IP permanently.]

PS. I dont have this directory. and attackers are trying to access it. 
[image: this is action's snapshot.]

if You can help me out in this then please. Or you can suggest me any good ddos protected reverse proxy too.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible with [IP Firewall](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/217074967) and/or [Rate limiting](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/235240767)